# MySQL - Error with JOIN and/or CASE Statement - Returning Random Row

Tags: mysql, database, left-join, case

I have a Query Running checking to see if a student is in a class and their attendance:

This is my query:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT student.Student_ID as 'Student_ID',
                             CASE when class.class_id is null then 'No Class ATM' else class.class_id end as 'Class_ID',
                             CASE when Attendance.Attendance_Status is null then 'No attendance taken' else Attendance.Attendance_Status end as 'Attendance_Status'
                    FROM Student
                      LEFT JOIN Student_Has_Class ON(student_has_class.student_id = student.student_id)
                      LEFT JOIN class ON class.class_id = student_has_class.class_id
                          AND NOW() between class.class_start_timestamp and class.class_end_timestamp
                      LEFT JOIN Subject ON(class.subject_id = subject.subject_id)
                      LEFT JOIN Attendance on(Attendance.class_id = class.class_ID
                          AND Attendance.student_id = student.student_id)
                    WHERE Student.student_id = 1;
```

However, whenever a student has a class, it seems to return a row which is shouldn't do, shown below:

[image: MySQL Result of Query]

The bottom row of the above result is the only row it should return (the bottom row data is correct), it shouldn't return the top row. The above result is saying "The Student is supposed to be in a class but no attendance has been taken yet"

I thin it may be a problem with either the CASE statement or JOIN.

What I am basically asking is why is the top row there and does anyone know how to remove it?

Comment: A quick guess - try to remove `LEFT` from `LEFT JOIN class` statement (iow - `JOIN class`).

Comment: That removed the row, but then when the student isn't in a class it returns an empty set, where I would like it to return the top row when the student isn't in a class, i just do not want the row when the student has a class, if you see what I mean. Really Strange.

Comment: have you tried puttin an ifnull around the class_id ? that way you can set something only if it's null, if you need to check if it's empty, you need to use an "if" and NOT "ifnull" because ifnull checks for NULL and not for empty strings

Comment: Would you be able to give a visual example if possible?